# What is the best way to disable a javascript files on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a child theme on wordpress and i would like to disable a Js on mobile and tablets viewports. Which method is the best :

- to load my javascripts on **functions.php** and use **wp_is_mobile** of wordpress to enqueue or dequeue ?
- Or load my javascripts in the **header.php** and use

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

?

I'm a newbie, and all i'm testing doesn't work.

Comment: That's up to you, and opinion based, both will work just fine, but why not just use what's built in Wordpress, and not load the script at all on mobile platforms

Comment: That's i want to do but i don't know how to do and where to do it, How i can say : "scrollmagic.js disappear on mobile" ? Actually i call my script in my own functions.php like this : `function scrjsenqeue() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll_magic', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollmagic.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scrjsenqeue' );`

Comment: I updated my answer to alter what you did and make it more efficient.

Comment: Your are great you both ! Thank you i'll do that ! Last question, the wp_is_mobile detect browser on mobile or the resize of the screen ?

Comment: I've tried with a browser mobile emulator, and i think all works fine, I'll cry of joy ! A big big thank for you both !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment from adeneo. If the scripts are being loaded by the parent theme using the wp_enqueue_script function you could add this to your child themes functions file:

```
function scrjsenqeue() { 
  if( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll_magic', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollmagic.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',true );
  } 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scrjsenqeue' );
```

I would add the check before enqueueing the files and not just dequeue them after.

Comment: Actually my scripts are added in a js folder in my child theme and i'm lost i've tried so many method since 5 days. I call my script like this : `function scrjsenqeue() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll_magic', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollmagic.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scrjsenqeue' );`  And after that if i put `if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
 function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'scroll_magic' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
}` With this all will work fine ?